# Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. While Running the App

Tags: react-native-cli

After running the app I am getting this > Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
25 actionable tasks: 25 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\Pallavi\React\Redux\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.GFGPagination (aka com.redux:style/Theme.GFGPagination) not found.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:C:\Users\Pallavi\React\Redux\android\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:14: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.GFGPagination (aka com.redux:style/Theme.GFGPagination) not found.

So I run the command in android  i.e ./gradlew.bat installDebug then I got that error that I have mention in question